# Matching a string if it contains all words of a list in python

Tags: python, string

I have a number of long strings and I want to match those that contain all **words** of a given list.

```
keywords=['special','dreams']
search_string1="This is something that manifests especially in dreams"
search_string2="This is something that manifests in special cases in dreams"
```

I want only search_string2 matched. So far I have this code:

```
if all(x in search_text for x in keywords):
   print("matched")
```

The problem is that it will also match search_string1. Obviously I need to include some regex matching that uses \w or or \b, but I can't figure out how I can include a regex in the `if all` statement.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `all(re.search(fr'\b{x}\b', search_text) for x in keywords)` or something similar? `re.search` returns a "Falsey" `None` if no matches are found which would work for the `all` function.

Answer (score 2):

Could be not the best idea, but we could check if one set is a part of another set:

```
keywords = ['special', 'dreams']

strs = [
  "This is something that manifests especially in dreams",
  "This is something that manifests in special cases in dreams"
]

_keywords = set(keywords)
for s in strs:
  s_set = set(s.split())
  if _keywords.issubset(s_set):
    print(f"Matched: {s}")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex to do the same but I prefer to just use python.

string classes in python can be split to list of words. (join can join a list to string). while using `word in list_of_words` will help you understand if word is in the list.

```
keywords=['special','dreams']
found = True
for word in keywords:
    if not word in search_string1.split():
        found = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Axe319's comment works and is closest to my original question of how to solve the problem using regex. To quote the solution again:

`all(re.search(fr'\b{x}\b', search_text) for x in keywords)`

Thanks to everyone!